# How to change config of vCenter Server Appliance (5.5) vm from ESXi host?

Tags: vmware, esxi

I want to enable (set to true) memoryHotAddEnabled and cpuHotAddEnabled on the  vCenter Server Appliance.

I can't user powerCLI since it needs a vCenter Server Appliance to connect to and to enable HotAdd the VM needs to be powered off.

I guess my googlefu is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can connect PowerCLI to a host instance of ESXi without needing to go through vCenter.

Otherwise, I would enable SSH and use esxcli to make the change.